# Deleting git/github commits history(previous ones) while staying with the latest commit

Tags: git, github

I am currently on a commit named '3' (let's say). Previously I have commits named '2', '1'. Inadvertently, I added some secret keys on commit '2'. I then removed the file from my workspace and then committed under name '3'. How can I remove the commit '2' from git and github history while staying with the latest commit '3'. I just want to have all the files/changes that are present on commit '3' and have my last commit to be '1'.

I had searched here and there and found about `rebase`, `reflog` but couldn't get a clear cut idea of how to solve this particular issue.

Edited.
I had all three of them pushed to github.

Comment: interactive rebase, then pick commit 1 and 3, comment out commit 2, then push with force option

Comment: what is interactive rebase?

Comment: see Tim's answer

Comment: Note that if you pushed commit 2 (with the secrets) *to* GitHub at any point, you should assume that these secrets are now known everywhere. They might not be, but there are various people who crawl GitHub looking for new stuff, and they might have grabbed your commit the second it became available.

Comment: I see, surely a mistake I did...but how can I now remove from the github history...Also I have edited the question and you can see I have commited and pushed all the 3 changed into the github.

Comment: @torek, is there a way?

Comment: You can contact GitHub themselves and have them scrub *their* systems. But it's too late. Remember that copying data (to flash drives etc) is nearly free. You should always assume the Bad Guys already did it, and have taken the flash drive home (or wherever) and have your information for sale on the black market, if it has any value.

Comment: thanx @torek for replying!

Answer (score 0):

If you *haven't* yet pushed, and you're also certain that you don't want anything from the second commit, then interactive rebase comes to the rescue:

```
# from your branch
git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

This will bring up a screen showing you the last 3 commits, from oldest to newest:

```
pick d83pcnd commit 1
pick 3jsu83m commit 2
pick w2kx9wk commit 3
```

From the editor, simply *delete* the line for the second commit, leaving you with:

```
pick d83pcnd commit 1
pick w2kx9wk commit 3
```

Now exit the editor and save, which should automatically start the rebase.  You may get merge conflicts as the work from the third commit is replayed on top of the first commit.

Note that since, under this assumption, you haven't pushed yet from the second commit onwards, you may just do a regular push:

```
# from your branch
git push origin your_branch
```

Now for the tricky part.  If you *have* pushed that 2nd commit already to the remote, then you may still do the above steps, but do a force push instead at the very end.  *However*, keep in mind that someone else may already have seen the secret keys.  So, if you have already pushed, the cat is out of the bag and you should probably regenerate the keys.

Comment: I see that this is useful if we are about to push commit 3 into gitub. But since I have done it already can you please figure out any other method that might work in my case.

Comment: _might_ work is the keyword here.  If you really pushed the 2nd commit, then you must assume the keys have been compromised.  There is no guarantee in this case.

Comment: I had deleted and created new keys, but one of  service that I'm using  is complaining that is exposed publicly in github. So, I just want that file to be removed from my commit history in github.

Answer (score 0):

Rebase branch into another. Rebasing streamlines commits history, but is better
done locally, never on server unless authorised [2 steps]:

1. position HEAD pointer to the branch to be rebased, here, for instance, `branch-to-rebase`, or `2` in your case:

```
git checkout branch-to-rebase
```

2. rebase it into the `master` branch, for instance (`3`, in your case). Then it is easy to do a fast-forward merge with `git checkout master` followed by `git merge branch-to-rebase`

```
git rebase master
```

Alternatively, in just one step:

```
git rebase master branch-to-rebase
```

= `git checkout branch-to-rebase` + `git rebase master`